# How to set a web page on FireBase?

Tags: ios, web, firebase

Is it possible to simply set up a tiny web page on FireBase to access some of the data produced by my iOS app?
The iOS app being already registered and working with FireBase.
Seeking the web makes me think the answer should be YES. But I haven’t found any simple and clear solution on how to do it.

Comment: The Firebase documentation contains all the information you'll need. See the [iOS quick start](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/quickstart.html) and the [Web quick start](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/quickstart.html).

Comment: I have already read that before writing this post. It seems I have to set up my own server, running "npm install firebase --save". I was hoping for a simpler solution. (The servers I happened to try didn't have npm)

Answer (score 1):

You can access your Firebase data with the Firebase Dashboard when you log into your account on the Firebase website.

Comment: Yes, that is "true". But when I write "to simply set up a tiny web page on FireBase to access some of the data", I mean a web page for an end user, without having to log in (sorry not being precise enough).

Comment: Got it. So the answer is no, you cannot setup a website 'on firebase' as it's not a web development environment. But, you can certainly put together a front end with HTML/Javascript and access data with that, or leverage Firebase hosting